# Generating a normally distributed random variable that has range [1, 3] in R

Tags: r, normal-distribution

I want to generate a normally distributed random variable that has range [1, 3].

Specifically, I tried the following R code:

```
x1 <- runif(100, 1, 2)
x2 <- rnorm(100, 0, 0.3)

V <- 1 + x1 + x2
```

Then, `V` follows a normal distribution (conditional on `x1`) and is roughly concentrated on [1, 3].

But, I want to make `V` to have range [1, 3]. That is, all elements should be in [1, 3], not roughly on [1, 3]:

```
min(V)
[1] 1
max(V)
[1] 3
```

I have no idea how to do.
Is there a technique for this task?

Comment: "Normal" distributions are theoretically infinite. Do you instead need to use the _truncated_ normal distribution? (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/truncnorm/)

Comment: There are several problems with your sample code and explanation. (1) `runif(1,2)` produces a warning and a single `NaN`, since you're asking for `1` obs with a min of `2` and a default `max=1`. (2) `rnorm(0,1)` produces `0` obs with a mean of `1` and a default `sd=1`. (3) Even if we interpret your numbers to be ranges and ignore the missing `n=` argument, it isn't clear how you expect addition of a bounded random distribution and an unbounded one to result in a `[1,3]` sample.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it reproducible, including starting with `set.seed(42)` or some number), non-zero sample sizes, and actual ranges and a discussion about what kind of distribution you expect (i.e., must it be centered on 2 or do you want to scale whatever values you get into a `[1,3]` range?)

Comment: @r2evans I am so sorry about the no-replicable example. Now, I edited the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the support of any normal distribution is the whole real number line, the only way to get what you are looking for is to draw a sample and then normalize it into your specified range. As r2evans points out, there are theoretical problems with any such approach. However, a simple implementation of it would be

```r
rnorm_limits <- function(n, min = 1, max = 3) {
  x <- rnorm(n)
  x <- (max - min) * x/diff(range(x))
  return(x - min(x) + min)
}
```

Testing, we have:

```r
set.seed(1)

hist(rnorm_limits(100))
```

[image]

And of course the range will be exactly that specified:

```r
range(rnorm_limits(100))
#> [1] 1 3
```

Comment: The "only" way?  Some others would be truncation as mentioned by @r2evans, or transformation (e.g. applying an inverse logistic transform).  Of course, as you mentioned in your first line, none of these gives a sample from a normal distribution.

Comment: @user2554330 it's a fair point, and I did pause as I wrote the word 'only', but I thought that, reading between the lines, this must be what the OP meant. A sample from a truncated normal doesn't have the _exact_ range [1, 3], nor does a beta nor does an inverse logistic transform. If we want to guarantee that the numbers 1 and 3 are in the data set, but the data were drawn from a normal distribution, I think normalization _is_ the only way. Happy to be shown a counter-example though.

Comment: Another way would be to find the joint distribution of a sample of size `n` (that's easy), and condition on the min and max values being as specified (not as easy, but not impossible; I think it's a truncated normal for n-2 of them plus the endpoints).  Or just add min and max to a sample of size n-2 using any other method that doesn't hit the endpoints.

Comment: @AllanCameron Thank you so much for the informative comment. I was confused some statistical facts about normal distributions. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a distribution with a bell-shaped density function centered at 2 and with endpoints at 1 and 3, you can construct it from a Beta(a,a) distribution:

```r
a <- 4
simulations <- 2*rbeta(100, a, a) + 1
```

By increasing the value of `a`, the distribution becomes more concentrated around 2.

Here is the theoretical density:

```r
a <- 4
x <- seq(1, 3, length.out = 200)
y <- dbeta((x-1)/2, a, a)/2
plot(x, y, type = "l")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach, but you would have to sacrifice the assumption that always 100% of values lay in [1, 3], and be satisfied with something like, at least 99.99% of values lay in [1, 3].

This is different from rescaling a standard normal distribution to always fit into [1, 3] completely, because the resulting distribution is going to have varying width (standard deviation), depending on whether there was an "outlier" or not in the random generation of the standard normal distribution. The whole distribution would be rescaled to make the outlier lay between [1, 3].

My approach is about setting the width (standard deviation) in a way, that for an infinitely large sample, e.g. 99.99% of values lay in between [1, 3].

You would have to reformulate the range as a percentage of the area under the normal distribution that you wish to cover. An area of 100% is always resulting in a range from -infinity to +infinity. So you have to step down on the area of the normal distribution that you want to be covered between [1, 3]. Let's say you want 99% of the area to be between 1 and 3.

You would have to use the `sd` argument to supply a standard deviation to `rnorm()` which is defining the normal distribution in a way that 99% of the area is between 1 and 3.

How to calculate that specific standard deviation?
We can use `qnorm()` to get the limit value of a certain area. This area is ranging from -infinity to `p`. When we put `p =  0.005`, we say: Give me the `x` value left of which lays 0.05% of the distribution.

As the normal distribution is symmetrical, we determine p by halving what is leftover by 99% of 100% = 1 %. We split 1% in half and say: 0.5% should lay below 1 and 0.5% should lay above 3.

All that is left to supply the mean of our distribution to the `qnorm()`. It should be the center of your given range. In your case, this is 2.

So we know the desired outcome of `qnorm(p = 0.005, mean = 2, sd = ???)`: It should be 1. We have to set `sd` in a way that the result is 1.

I did this with trial and error, approximating 1 and got to this point:

```r
qnorm(0.005, mean = 2, sd = 0.388223)
#> 1.000004
```

So, in turn:

```r
rnorm(mean = 2, sd = 0.388223, n = 100)
```

should give you random values of which ~99% fall in between the range [1, 3].

[image: histogram of normal distribution ranging from 1 to 3]

You could go more extreme by saying 99.99% should be inside [1, 3], approximating your goal of 100%.

- p = (100% - 99.99%)/2 = 0.01% / 2 = 0.005% = 0.00005
- same steps as above, optimize `sd` so that

```r
qnorm(0.00005, mean = 2, sd = ???) == 1
```

- pluck `sd` into your `rnorm()` call.

For the 99.99% example, `sd` would be ~ 0.25703. This is likely a bit extreme, because the values are more like [1.4, 2.8] then, but if you want to be sure, you can choose it. This would be suitable for large samples.

```r
rnorm(mean = 2, sd = 0.25703, n = 10000) |> hist()
```

[image: histogram of normal distribution with 10000 observations range 1 to 3 and sd = 0.25...]